# How to remove background completely in BottomAppBar widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have trouble removing the background of the BottomAppBar widget. I want the black area showed in the picture I attach (to visualize what I want to eliminate) to become transparent, because I don't like how it blends with the background.

How can I do this?

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:money_manager/utils/constants.dart';

class NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final int pageIndex;
  final Function(int) onTap;

  const NavBar({super.key, required this.pageIndex, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          color: primaryDark,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              navItem(
                  Icons.home_filled,
                  pageIndex == 0,
                  onTap: () => onTap(0)),
              navItem(
                  Icons.insert_chart_outlined_outlined,
                  pageIndex == 1,
                  onTap: () => onTap(1)),
              const SizedBox(width: 60),
              navItem(
                  Icons.wallet,
                  pageIndex == 2,
                  onTap: () => onTap(2)),
              navItem(
                  Icons.person,
                  pageIndex == 3,
                  onTap: () => onTap(3)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget navItem(IconData icon, bool selected, {Function()? onTap}) {
  return Expanded(
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already made the background of the bottom app bar transparent, the next step is to make the `Scaffold` body extends below it.

```dart
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  // ...
)
```

About the [extendBody](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/extendBody.html) property of `Scaffold`:

> This property is often useful when the bottomNavigationBar has a non-rectangular shape, like CircularNotchedRectangle, which adds a FloatingActionButton sized notch to the top edge of the bar. In this case **specifying `extendBody: true` ensures that scaffold's body will be visible through the bottom navigation bar's notch**.